# What happens when a casted pointer has an increment operator?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, compiler-construction, programming-languages

For example:

```
int x[100];
void *p;

x[0] = 0x12345678;
x[1] = 0xfacecafe;
x[3] = 0xdeadbeef;

p = x;
((int *) p) ++ ;

printf("The value = 0x%08x", *(int*)p);
```

Compiling the above generates an lvalue required error on the line with the ++ operator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The cast creates a temporary pointer of type `int *`. You can't increment a temporary as it doesn't denote a place to store the result.

In C and C++ standardese, `(int *)p` is an **rvalue**, which roughly means an expression that can only occur on the right-hand side of an assignment.

`p` on the other hand is an **lvalue**, which means it can validly appear on the left-hand side of an assignment. Only lvalues can be incremented.

Comment: In C++, lvalue and rvalue have very little to do with assignments. `array_name` is an lvalue that cannot occur on the left-hand side of an assignment, and `std::string("hello")` is an rvalue which can.

Comment: @FredOverflow : Yes correct. BTW I added an answer addressing those issues. :)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `((int *) p)` treats the pointer stored inside the variable `p` is a pointer to int. If you want to treat the *variable* itself as a pointer to int variable (and then increment it), use a reference cast:

```
((int *&) p) ++ ;
```

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to larsmans for pointing to the right direction.

I took the liberty of digging deeper into this.  So for future reference, according to sections 6.5.2.4 and 6.5.4 of the C99 standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> 6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators
>
> Constraints
>
> The operand of the postfix increment
>   or decrement operator shall have
>   qualified or unqualified real or
>   pointer type and shall be a modifiable
>   lvalue
> ..
> ..
>   6.5.4 Cast operators
>   ..
>   ..
>   [Footnote] 89) A cast
>   does not yield an lvalue. Thus, a cast
>   to a qualified type has the same
>   effect as a cast to the unqualified
>   version of the type.

Note: This only applies to C.  C++ may handle casts differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the intended result with

```
p = (int*)p + 1;
```

Using the increment operator on a dereferenced pointer to `p`, which is an lvalue, also works:

```
(*(int**)&p)++;
```

However, the latter is not portable, since `(void*)p` might not have the same representation as `(int*)p`.

Comment: Your first suggestion is correct; the second one is undefined behaviour (strict aliasing violation)

Answer (score 0):

Rvalue expression `((int *) p)` creates and temporary of type `int*` on which operator `++` cannot be applied.

`++` requires an lvalue as its operand.

As @FredOverflow mentions `lvalues` and `rvalues` have very little to do with assignment.

Arrays are lvalues still they cannot be assigned to because they are non-modifiable. 
`std::string("Prasoon")` is an rvalue expression still it can occur on the left side of assignment operator because we are allowed to call member functions( `operator =` in this case) on temporaries.

Comment: There are no scalar temporaries :) The result of evaluating the rvalue `((int *) p)` is just a value.

Comment: @FredOverflow : I don't think the statement "There are no scalar temporaries" is 100% correct. What do you have to say about `const int& ref = int()`? Doesn't it create a scalar temporary?

Comment: `int()` is the same as `0`, but you have a point: binding to a reference-to-const can implicitly create a scalar temporary. How about this: "There is no *expression* whose result is a scalar temporary."

Comment: @FredOverflow : `const int& ref = int()` as a whole is an expression, right? It can create a scalar temporary. So I've got problems with your second statement "There is no...." as well. :-)

Comment: @FredOverflow : Does the Standard explicitly say "you can't have a scalar temporary" ? I think no.

Comment: `const int& ref = int()` is not an expression, it's a definition. (If it were an expression, you could pass it as an argument to a function, for example.)

Comment: @FredOverflow : Ah! Right! Missed that completely. Now I think I know what you think I know. :-)

Comment: Section 12.2 does not mention scalars explicitly, but it starts off with "Temporaries of *class type* are created in various contexts". I know, that does not mean much :)

Comment: By the way, couldn't the compiler simply rewrite `const int& x = 0;` to `const int x = 0;` (without the reference), and the programmer could not tell a difference?

Comment: @FredOverflow : I haven't seen the code that gets generated in both the case but the generated code in both the cases would pretty much be the same IMO. There is no need for that reference, right!! :)